# Rigify. How to add a controller?

Tags: rigging

I am rigging a human monkey character. I use Rigify to rig And I add a tail by myself.

[image]

But when I try to add a controller.

[image]

It shows this.

[image]

Why am I unable to add it?

Comment: The error doesn't have to do with your tail. It has to do with the face. I can't say exactly what happened but you probably deleted the face partially but some of the bones were left in the meta rig.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!